# Unable to select Date Picker in Android using Appium

Tags: android, xpath, automation, appium, mobile-application

**The problem**
I'm unable to select the date-picker in an android device using appium.
I have tried three ways but still am unable to change.
Kindly suggest me how do I proceed in this.

**Details**
I have tried using the Xpath, the inspector is inspecting the element but it is not altering the values I provided through .sendkeys.
So, kindly if there's any suggestions please pass it, so that it helps me to move forward.

Try #1

```
((AndroidElement)(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']//android.widget.Button[@index=0]"))).tap(1, 2);
((AndroidElement)(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']//android.widget.Button[@index=0]"))).tap(1, 2);
((AndroidElement)(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']//android.widget.Button[@index=0]"))).tap(1, 2);
```

Try #2

```
List pick = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText"));
pick.get(0).sendKeys("24");;
pick.get(1).sendKeys("5");
pick.get(2).sendKeys("1991");
```

Try #3

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='0']")).sendKeys("5");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='1']")).sendKeys("5");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.NumberPicker[@index='2']")).sendKeys("1990")
```

[Date Picker in appium](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8nFk.jpg)

Comment: Facing same issue :(